# Delete Parent node keeping all its child elements in nested XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am having nested XML, I want to remove only parent node < items> in xml document keeping all its child nodes.

```
<root>
  <items>
    <Product>
       <name> </name>
       <size> </size>
       <images>
          <img1></img1>
          <img2></img2>  
       </images>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <name> </name>
       <size> </size>
       <images>
          <img1></img1>
          <img2></img2>  
       </images>
    </Product>  
  </items>
</root>
```

Expected Output -

```
<root>
    <Product>
       <name> </name>
       <size> </size>
       <images>
          <img1></img1>
          <img2></img2>  
       </images>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <name> </name>
       <size> </size>
       <images>
          <img1></img1>
          <img2></img2>  
       </images>
    </Product>  
</root>
```

I have researched & tried a lot, on removing the < items> node all its child nodes are also getting deleted. Please help if there is any way using DOMDocument or any other way in php.

Comment: While here is a valid node int the $firstChild property of the `item` node and insert the child before `item`. After that remove it.

Comment: @ThW if I'll insert new child before < item> then how would I'll remove that new node again. I don't want to change name of the node, but to remove it & want < product> node directly under the < root> node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ThW mentioned, you have to collect the child nodes in ITEMS, then insert them into ROOT, and finally delete ITEMS.

```
$input = "
<root>
 <items>
  <Product>
   <name> </name>
   <size> </size>
   <images>
    <img1></img1>
    <img2></img2>  
   </images>
  </Product>
  <Product>
   <name> </name>
   <size> </size>
   <images>
    <img1></img1>
    <img2></img2>  
   </images>
  </Product>
 </items>
</root>";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$ret = $doc->loadXML($input);
$root = $doc->firstChild;
$nodes_to_insert = array();
$nodes_to_remove = array();
foreach($root->childNodes as $items) {
    if($items->nodeName != "items") {
        continue;
    }
    $nodes_to_remove[] = $items;
    foreach($items->childNodes as $child) {
        if($child->nodeType != XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            continue;
        }
        $nodes_to_insert[] = $child;
    }
}
foreach($nodes_to_insert as $node) {
    $root->appendChild($node);
}
foreach($nodes_to_remove as $node) {
    $root->removeChild($node);
}
var_dump($doc->saveXML());
```

This code will search for all "items" tag within root, not only one. Inside "items", it will search all normal node (ELEMENT type, but no TEXT node, etc.)
In the last line there is a dump, but normally you will not see anything in a browser, because of the XML header line. But if you take a look at page source, the result will be shown.

PS: it is quite important to not modify xml structure when you walk it. That's why i do only collection first, then the insert and delete actions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Geza Boems answer is not exactly what I meant. Using Xpath you can fetch the `items` nodes for iteration. This is a stable result, so you can iterate it while modifying the DOM.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($input);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//items') as $itemsNode) {
  // as long that here is any child inside it
  while ($itemsNode->firstChild instanceof DOMNode) {
    // move it before its parent
    $itemsNode->parentNode->insertBefore($itemsNode->firstChild, $itemsNode);
  }
  // remove the empty items node
  $itemsNode->parentNode->removeChild($itemsNode);
}
echo $document->saveXML();
```